# ResolutionFailedException when register a Unity interceptor

Tags: c#, unity-container

I have this code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
        container.RegisterType<ITestInterception, TestInterception>(new TransientLifetimeManager(),
                                                 new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(),
                                                 new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>());


        container.Configure<Interception>()
                 .AddPolicy("MyPolicy")
                 .AddMatchingRule(new MemberNameMatchingRule("Test"))
                 .AddCallHandler<FaultHandler>();

        try
        {
            var tester = container.Resolve<ITestInterception>();
            tester.Test();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.GetType() + "\n\n");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class AlwaysMatchingRule : IMatchingRule
{
    public bool Matches(MethodBase member)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

interface ITestInterception
{
    void Test();
}

class TestInterception : ITestInterception
{
    public void Test()
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Null");
    }
}

class FaultHandler : ICallHandler
{
    public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invoke called");
        IMethodReturn result = getNext()(input, getNext);
        Exception e = result.Exception;
        if (e == null)
            return result;

        return input.CreateExceptionMethodReturn(new InvalidOperationException("In interceptor", e));
    }

    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

When it runs, I has ResolutionFailedException.

> Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   "TestUnity.ITestInterception", name = "(none)". Exception occurred
>   while: while resolving. Exception is: TypeLoadException - Type
>   'DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_ITestInterception_0e954c5db37c4c4ebf99acaee12e93f7'
>   from assembly 'Unity_ILEmit_InterfaceProxies, Version=0.0.0.0,

Can you explain me how to solve this problem?

Comment: which version of Unity are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InnerException` message says it all:

> Type 'DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_ITestInterception_c8a0c8bf8a3d48a5b7f85924fab5711f' from assembly 'Unity_ILEmit_InterfaceProxies, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' **is attempting to implement an inaccessible interface**.

You need to make your interface public:

```
public interface ITestInterception
{
    void Test();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @Roelf's answer is to allow the calling assembly access to internal interfaces/objects:

In the project that has your Unity configuration, under Properties, add:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Unity_ILEmit_InterfaceProxies")]
```